# gb4e and a0poster: glossed examples very small

Tags: fonts, fontsize, linguistics, gb4e, a0poster

I am trying to make a poster using the `a0poster` document class to produce a poster that contains glossed linguistic examples. For the linguistic examples, I am using the standard package `gb4e`. There seems to be a problem, however, since the first two lines of the example (that is the line containing the text in the original language and the second line containing the glosses) appear with really small font, while the last line (the translation) appears in normal font size. If anyone has an idea of how to circumvent this problem, I would be most grateful for their help!

I am attaching a screenshot to illustrate exactly what I mean.

[image]

Here is also the set of packages that I have loaded.

```
\documentclass[a0,landscape]{a0poster}
\usepackage{multicol}
\columnsep=100pt 
\columnseprule=3pt
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor} 

\usepackage{times} 

\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for including images
\graphicspath{{figures/}} % Location of the graphics files
\usepackage{booktabs} % Top and bottom rules for table
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption} % Required for specifying captions to tables and figures
\usepackage{amsfonts, amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, centernot, stmaryrd} % For math fonts, symbols and environments
\usepackage{wrapfig} % Allows wrapping text around tables and figures
\usepackage{gb4e}
\usepackage[mathscr]{euscript}
```

Any suggestions are deeply appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't explain why, but putting the code from cgloss4e.sty which defines the gloss commands into the preamble fixes it for me.

```
\documentclass{a0poster}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{gb4e}
% from cgloss4e.sty
\def\gll%                 % Introduces 2-line text-and-gloss.
   {\begin{flushleft}
     \ifx\@gsingle1%           conditionally force single spacing (hpk/MC)
        \vskip\baselineskip\def\baselinestretch{1}%
        \@selfnt\vskip-\baselineskip\fi%
    \bgroup
    \twosent
   }
\def\glll%                 % Introduces 3-line text-and-gloss.
   {\begin{flushleft}
     \ifx\@gsingle1%        conditionally force single spacing (hpk/MC)
        \vskip\baselineskip\def\baselinestretch{1}%
        \@selfnt\vskip-\baselineskip\fi%
    \bgroup
    \threesent
   }
\begin{document}
\begin{exe}
\ex
\gll Anna kauft heute ein Kleid\\
     Anna buys today a dress\\
\trans `Anna buys a dress today'
\end{exe}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just for future reference, that didn't work for me. This did the trick:

```
\documentclass{a0poster}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\let\eachwordone=\large 
\let\eachwordtwo=\large
```